# Debugging issue while trying to debug iOS Capacitor-based App

Tags: angular, debugging, capacitor, capacitor-plugin

I have an issue trying to debug an iOS Capacitor based App,
The issue is that the WebInsepctor doesn't show the project files that I'm supposed to use to set the breakpoints and start debugging
This is what I see when I open the WebInspector after I got the App up and running on the iOS Simulator
[image]

in the left side pan, there should be the project files through which I can go to set the breakpoints and start debugging, but as shown in the image they don't exist.

What did I do wrong?

Comment: what's your Capacitor version? there is a bug on Xcode 14.3 that prevent apps from being inspected and that has been fixed in Capacitor 4.8.0 and newer.

Comment: @JulioCesar, My xCode version is 14.2 and the Capacitor version is 5.0.4 which is the latest version

Comment: Ah, sorry, I misunderstood your problem. I was talking about the device not showing inspectable apps, but by your screenshot you are able to inspect. Have you tried clicking on the "Scripts" folder? I think that should then expand and show all your scripts.

Comment: @JulioCesar, Unfortunately, the files are not under the Scripts, I'm expecting some files with .ts, .html, and .css extensions and such files are not there.

Comment: .ts files get transpilled into .js files (because browsers don't know typescript), and bundlers usually put all the code together in a main.js or vendor.js or similar